# Telerik RadGrid Cast exception when populated with an array of objects by their parent type

Tags: c#, casting, telerik, radgrid

I have just come across a Casting Exception while using the Telerik RadGrid.

It occurs during the DataBind event if I have an array of objects as the datasource

`radgrid1.DataSource = new BaseObject[] { new ChildObject1(), new ChildObject2() };`

where the classes ChildObject1 and ChildObject2 both inherit from the class BaseObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer.

`var objects = new BaseObject[] { new ChildObject1(), new ChildObject2() };`
`radgrid1.DataSource = new List<BaseObject>(objects);`